# Create a Channel in agora.io

Tags: javascript, agora.io

I'm follow the Started guide about agora.io

https://docs.agora.io/en/Interactive%20Broadcast/initialize_web_live?platform=Web

but after create the client talk about join channel, and for this method it's a Channel name is necessary, but I don't know which channel enjoy an neither when I create the channel.

Answer (score 2):

To make a video call Agora provides the channel concept. If you are starting a video call, you have to specify a channel name and the token for authentication. The other person also needs to join on the same channel to talk to each other.

A Channel name can be any string within 64byte. Check what Agora documentation says:

> Unique channel name for the Agora RTC session in the string format.
> The string length must be less than 64 bytes. Supported character
> scopes are:
>
> 1. The 26 lowercase English letters: a to z.
> 2. The 26 uppercase English letters: A to Z.
> 3. The 10 digits: 0 to 9.
> 4. The space.
> 5. "!", "#","$", "%", "&", "(", ")", "+", "-", ":", ";", "<", "=", ".", ">", "?","@", "[", "]", "^", "_", " {", "}", "|", "~", ",".

The token is the one that can be created using AgoraSDK by providing the appId, appCertificate, channelName, uid, role, expiry. Please check Agora documentation for more details: https://docs.agora.io/en/Interactive%20Broadcast/token#generate-a-token

The implementation should be like the following diagram. The Channel and token generation should be done in the serverside. Hope it would clear all doubts about Agora.
[image]

Comment: Can  Guid be used as  a ChannelName?

Comment: @Adarshs it can be video_meet or any string